# GridView ComboBox - Bind selected element property

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, combobox, binding

**EDIT** : Working better, but still not perfect :

SelectedFace has been set as ComboElement (still couldn't manage to do the job without this additional parameter).

Still not working : When I create a new Tool, SelectedFace is updated correctly, but if I want to edit an existing one, no Update is made(no binding).

**End Edit**

I have a GridView, in which there is a ComboBox to select on which face each tool located.

I cannot manage to bind the selected value to my object property.

Here are the properties as declared in my `Tool` object :

```
    private long face = 0;
    public long Face
    {
        get { return face; }
        set
        {
            this.face = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Face");
        }
    }
    private ComboElement selectedFace;
    public ComboElement SelectedFace
    {
        get { return selectedFace; }
        set
        {
            this.selectedFace = value;
            this.Face = value.MyInt;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedFace");
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<ComboElement> comboFaceSlot=new ObservableCollection<ComboElement> { new ComboElement { MyInt = 0, MyString = "Web" }, new ComboElement { MyInt = 1, MyString = "Top" }, new ComboElement { MyInt = 2, MyString = "Bottom" }, new ComboElement { MyInt = 3, MyString = "Back" } };
    public ObservableCollection<ComboElement> ComboFaceSlot
    {
        get { return comboFaceSlot; }
        set
        {
            this.comboFaceSlot = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged("ComboFaceSlot");
        }
    }
```

Nota : At the beginning I had not the `SelectedFace` property, I added it thinking this would solve my problem, but it didn't.

And XAML is as following :

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Margin="5" BorderBrush="{StaticResource WindowBorderColor}" BorderThickness="3" Width="Auto"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListTools}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Length}" Binding="{Binding Path=Longueur}" Width="100" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Diameter}" Binding="{Binding Path=Diameter}" Width="100" />

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Face}">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ComboFaceSlot}" DisplayMemberPath="MyString" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFace}" Width="100" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Angle}" Binding="{Binding Path=Angle}" Width="100" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Also forgot, my ComboElement I use for all Comboboxes of my project :

```
public class ComboElement
{
    private long myInt=-1;
    public long MyInt
    {
        get { return myInt; }
        set { myInt = value; }
    }
    private string myString="";
    public string MyString
    {
        get { return myString; }
        set { myString = value; }
    }
    public ComboElement()
    {

    }
    public ComboElement(long id, string name)
    {
        this.myInt = id;
        this.MyString = name;
    }

}
```

*Edit* : My ViewModel

```
private ObservableCollection<Tool> listTool = new ObservableCollection<Tool>();
public ObservableCollection<Tool> ListTool
{
    get { return listTool; }
    set
    {
        this.listTool = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("ListTool");
    }
}
private Machine cnc = new Machine();
public Machine CNC
{
   get { return cnc; }
   set { this.cnc = value;NotifyPropertyChanged("CNC"); }
}
public TableTools(Machine cnc)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.CNC = cnc;
    foreach(Tool slot in CNC.ListTool)
    {
        this.ListTool.Add(slot);
    }

    DataContext = this;
}
```

It lists a list of Tools, and I want to say on which face each element is located.
But for now something is going wrong, I tried to use several properties of my ComboBox as SelectedItem, SelectedValue, SelectedValuePath, but until now didn't manage to solve it.
Ideally, I would like to delete "SelectedFace" element, and use only "Face" property.

Comment: What is your DataContext set to? Is the ListTool collection's individual item have a property called ComboFaceSlot? Post full classes and your View too.

Comment: DataContext is set to my ViewModel.(maybe didn't understand question). Then yes, as you see in my code, I added to each Tool properties ComboFaceSlot and SelectedFace, cause I see no other way to do this.

Comment: @IvanJazz so I was mistaken, my Context is my Window (this), I set a property ListTool, that reads all the tools of my current machine. (Window's name is TableTools)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the Tool class like such in your question.

The root cause is not specifying the correct `SelectedValuePath` of your `ComboElement` object to be mapped to your `Tool` object's Face property as the `SelectedValue`.

Tool Class

```
public class Tool
{
    private ObservableCollection<ComboElement> comboFaceSlot = new ObservableCollection<ComboElement> { new ComboElement { MyInt = 0, MyString = "Web" }, new ComboElement { MyInt = 1, MyString = "Top" }, new ComboElement { MyInt = 2, MyString = "Bottom" }, new ComboElement { MyInt = 3, MyString = "Back" } };
    public ObservableCollection<ComboElement> ComboFaceSlot
    {
        get { return comboFaceSlot; }
        set
        {
            this.comboFaceSlot = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged("ComboFaceSlot");
        }
    }

    private long face = 0;
    public long Face
    {
        get { return face; }
        set
        {
           this.face = value;
           this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Face");
        }
    }
}
```

ToolWindow View

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Margin="5" BorderBrush="{StaticResource WindowBorderColor}" BorderThickness="3" Width="Auto"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListTools}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Length}" Binding="{Binding Path=Longueur}" Width="100" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Diameter}" Binding="{Binding Path=Diameter}" Width="100" />

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Face}">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ComboFaceSlot}"  
                          DisplayMemberPath="MyString" 
                          SelectedValuePath="MyInt"
                          SelectedValue="{Binding Face, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="100" />
            </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Angle}" Binding="{Binding Path=Angle}" Width="100" />
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: I told you in comment, that code is part of my object definition, not of the window.

Comment: ok so I try to be more clear : ComboFaceSlot, Face and SelectedFace are all described in my object(each individual tool), so I have a ComboBox for each Tool(each GridLine). in my ViewModel I don't have any ComboFaceSlot or Face properties, just an ObservableCollection<Tool>.

Comment: No need for `SelectedFace` anymore, but you do have to define `SelectedValuePath`.

Comment: I tried this also(SelectedPath/SelectedValuePath), but don't understand why, when I add a new line(new Tool), the Tool is correctly created with SelectedValue, but when I modify the SelectedValue, binding is not correctly made. I see it changed graphically in ComboBox, but Face is not Updated.

Comment: I'm guessing when you add a new Tool, you initialise the value of Face, but when you change the selection, since `SelectedValuePath` is not defined, it will assign null to your `SelectedValue`(Face). You need to provided BOTH `SelectedValuePath` and `SelectedValue`.

Comment: I did, in fact I did it already before creating "SelectedFace", and as it didn't work that's why I created it thinking that would work better. Now I again removed "SelectedFace", and trying again, but until now I couldn't find why Binding is not done.

Comment: Did you copy the provided XAML from above? It's working on my end.

Comment: I did, but in fact I believe the error is somewhere else, because I just noticed that even my Text columns are not updated too... will check all the dataGrid again

Comment: so I understood what is not working "as it should", the binding is working from the beginning BUT : if I only modify the ComboBox, no update is done. If I modify a TextColumn, and clicking on "Tab" to change field, no Update is done. To take in account changes, I need to validate a TextColumn typing "Enter", and it updates all fields at the same time.

Comment: that's ok I solved it, so I just needed to add on every bindings , `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`, and now all is working like a charm, thanks anyway for your help

Comment: just please edit your answer with `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`, useful information for who will read your answer